# Better way to join bezier curve to bezier (half) circle?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Conceptually, I am trying to achieve what Merge can do with a mesh: select an end vertex from each of two bezier paths and merge them together with only one vertex as the result.

This is the only way I've come close to acceptable results, but there are still imperfections, so I'm wondering if more experienced modelers have techniques to share.

1. Add a Bezier Circle
2. Select all the vertices
3. Change the handle types to Free (in essence, lock in the vertex control point parameters)
4. Select two adjacent vertices, hit X, choosing to delete Segment (giving you a hemisphere)
5. Add a Bezier Curve
6. Position the curve so one vertex is near an end vertex in the hemisphere curve
7. Select the two vertices that you positioned close to one another
8. Press F to Make Segment

When I do that, no matter what my normals are doing, I get a loop as a segment between the two vertices.  To minimize this, before step 8 I have tried changing the handle type at the end of the bezier curve to be free and then scaled down to near zero its control point on the side towards the hemisphere, and doing the same to the corresponding control point on the vertex of the hemisphere that I'll be joining.  But I still get an additional segment (to be expected given the method, but not what I want).

This is in Blender 2.6, if that matters.

Comment: For step 4, select two  adjacent vertices and delete the segment will give a 3/4 circle, not a half cicle. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Right: I wasn't clear.  I then deleted the extra vertex.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After step 8, click <kbd>LMB</kbd> once or twice to select the useless point, then <kbd>X</kbd> > **Vertex** to delete it.

Actually, it's recommended to enable **Snapping** so that the two vertex can be overlapped, that brings the new segment with zero length.

You can also use a nice addon called **[Curve Tools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Curve_Tools)** (*by Mackraken*). I recommend to use the modified version **[Curve Tools 2](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?221213-Tools-for-curves/page7)** (*by Mackraken and guy lateur*), which can handle this perfectly while keeping curvatures.

Added a short **[demo video](http://youtu.be/S9U2MQVhOZ4)** (01:35).

---

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3dUJWMm9wdkRpR2s/edit?usp=sharing) is the lastest version, in case you cannot access Blendernation.com. (File > Download)

Comment: Of course!  Just delete one of the vertices!  Thank you!

Comment: That's awesome!  Thanks for the additional info and for taking the time to make a video.  That add-on is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Sadly blenderartists.org is not accepting my registration information.  I'll keep looking for curve tools 2 on the web...

Comment: Could you attach curvetools2 here?  I can't find it anywhere else and blenderartists.org isn't accepting my registration requests (via web and email).

Comment: @tobinjim OK. I've tried to upload it to Google dirve for you.See the updated answer.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you again!  Now I need to go watch your video again to see how you got the plugin to act on your setup :)